# I am new to r. How can I convert a data frame variable value from a number to a name? See code below

Tags: r

```
>may_jfk<-may_df%>%filter(origin=="JFK")
>may_jfk
> str(may_jfk)
'data.frame':   9397 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ origin  : chr  "JFK" "JFK" "JFK" "JFK" ...
 $ flight  : int  413 701 5716 715 315 1169 303 1657 203 195 ...
 $ month   : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ dep_time: int  9 537 555 557 603 605 605 605 621 621 ...
```

How can I change $month from "5" to "May"?

Comment: Try `library(lubridate); month(5, label = T)` as an example. Then apply this function to the whole column.

Comment: If you want to convert just one column, you should use : `df$col < - as.character(df$col)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `month.abb` in `base R`

```
may_jfk$month <- month.abb[may_jfk$month]
```